# "Resource with same name already exists" with sendResourceAtURL?

Tags: ios, ios8, multipeer-connectivity

I'm using the `MultiPeer` framework on iOS 8 and sending files using `sendResourceAtURL`.  Occasionally, the transfer fails.  The sender's completion handler receives the `error: Error Domain=MCSession Code=2 "Resource with same name already exists" UserInfo=0x170663d00 {NSLocalizedDescription=Resource with same name already exists}`

I'm assuming that the there is a conflict with the name of the temp file created on the receiving side, but I am good about cleaning up this files after each transfer--something you need to do, but isn't documented.

Has anyone encountered this error?  Any work around?

Comment: Did you find any solution back then?

Comment: It isn’t documented but that temp file is your file and you need to take care of it/delete it or move it when you’re done.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I'l try it and update here for others as well